# Follow/Unfollow Link returning wrong value

Tags: php, mysql

more issues with following and unfollowing!

This time there is supposed to be a check to the database of if i'm following a user or not. If I am, its supposed to display "Unfollow", if i'm not its supposed to display "follow"

I have a user_follow table that contains the ID of the follower and the user followed, under the names "follower" and "user"

The code to get these:

```
$check_following = mysql_query("SELECT `follower`, `user` FROM user_follow WHERE `user`=$p_id'");
$follow_query = mysql_fetch_array($check_following);
```

p_id is the profile i'm looking at. The if statement:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $p_id != $_SESSION['id'])
      {
          if ($follow_query['follower'] == $_SESSION['id'] && $follow_query['user'] ==$p_id)
               { 
                 echo 'Unfollow';
               } 
          else { 
                 echo 'Follow';
               } 
 }
```

Problem is, unfollow shows on 1 out of the 3 profiles i'm following, and follow shows on 2 profiles i'm following, echoing `$follow_query['follower']` shows 1, which isn't me (also shows 1 for another user)

Any ideas?

Thanks guys

Comment: will you var_dump your $follow_query variable

Comment: sure, for the $follow_query: array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["follower"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" ["user"]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: ok does the array contains 'follower' as key. It  seems that you should use mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, i've updated my previous comment with what's being returned with $follow_query. Sorry, I'm very new to mysql/php

Comment: ok, Replace this code $follow_query = mysql_fetch_array($check_following); with $follow_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_following); then check

Comment: ok sorry. I was bit late

Comment: with assoc, it shows: array(2) { ["follower"]=> string(1) "1" ["user"]=> string(1) "2" }

I went on another profile for this, i was on my own profile for the previous comment, my ID is 3 and the profile i'm on is 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns more than one row if there are more results form the sql query. to properly iterate the results use : `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){$array[] = $row;}`